# Replace the values in the column with the results

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace the values from the column in a dataset with the results for the values in the column.     Example: My data set has

```
id          tslot         A
1   2014-11-02 22:45:00   89    
1   2014-10-26 09:15:00   762
1   2014-10-26 11:00:00   25
1   2014-10-26 11:15:00   762
1   2014-10-26 12:00:00   25    
1   2014-10-26 13:00:00   25
1   2014-10-26 13:45:00   25    
1   2014-10-26 14:45:00   902
1   2014-10-26 15:45:00   902
```

After running some function I got some values for the column A.

```
          Emb_A
762.0   -0.237305
89.0    -0.033929
902.0   -0.237330
25.0    -0.237300
1176.0  -0.237300
827.0   -0.237312
1227.0  -0.237301
```

So I want to add one more column for the dataset and place the Emb_A values in the column.

My expected output is:

```
id        tslot            A        Emb_A
1   2014-11-02 22:45:00   89    -0.033929
1   2014-10-26 09:15:00   762   -0.237305
1   2014-10-26 11:00:00   25    -0.237300
1   2014-10-26 11:15:00   762   -0.237305
1   2014-10-26 12:00:00   25    -0.237300
1   2014-10-26 13:00:00   25    -0.237300
1   2014-10-26 13:45:00   25    -0.237300
1   2014-10-26 14:45:00   902   -0.237330
1   2014-10-26 15:45:00   902   -0.237330
```

Comment: If the index of your returned Series is unique, you are probably looking to [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) column `'A'`

Comment: Maybe but I am not sure as I am new to this. Can you explain in detail if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Define the function to be run on column-`A`

Then use `apply` method to apply it to entire column using a lambda function.

Example:

```
def your_function(x):
    # x is individual value from desired column
    # operate on x here. For eg. square(x)
    return x**2

df["Emb_A"] = df["A"].apply(lambda x: your_function(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [89,762,25,762,25,25,25,902,902]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Emb_A': [-0.237305,-0.033929,-0.237330,-0.237300, -0.237300,-0.237312,-0.237301]}, index=[762.0,89.0,902.0,25.0,1176.0,827.0,1227.0])
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['Emb_A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: float(df1[df1['index']==float(x)]['Emb_A']))
print(df)

     A     Emb_A
0   89 -0.033929
1  762 -0.237305
2   25 -0.237300
3  762 -0.237305
4   25 -0.237300
5   25 -0.237300
6   25 -0.237300
7  902 -0.237330
8  902 -0.237330
```

**Update:**

```
df = df.merge(df1, left_on='A', right_on='index')
df.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)
     A     Emb_A
0   89 -0.033929
1  762 -0.237305
2  762 -0.237305
3   25 -0.237300
4   25 -0.237300
5   25 -0.237300
6   25 -0.237300
7  902 -0.237330
8  902 -0.237330
```

Comment: The data set is huge so I tried to replace the values with the columns but failed in doing so. Can you edit your code?